# Best template for Poster presentation :First time(Conference)

Tags: conference, poster

My paper has been accepted in a conference related to computer science.
I need to prepare a Poster for presentation. This is my first time, I tried to find some good templates but ended up nothing. I am confused. Could you please advise some good templates where I can prepare a poster? and please give some suggestions to prepare a good poster. Thanks

Comment: I am afraid a good answer should cover too many aspects. Could be possible that you look at old posters from the group,  or even you work on that with a colleague eventually presenting at the same conference? At least from a graphical pov having homogeneity is good for the recognition, though it mainly concerns the group head.

Comment: Your institute might have a poster template available

Answer (score 6):

Definitely worthwhile looking at previous posters from your conferences and other plus hunting around for posters from your department and team. There are some good sites that go through the background and with more concrete suggestions.

For a more traditional style of poster - https://colinpurrington.com/tips/poster-design/

There has been a spate of new poster styles if you are feeling adventurous - [London School of Economics](https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/impactofsocialsciences/2018/05/11/how-to-design-an-award-winning-conference-poster/)

-

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong – but don't the last two links basically feature identical content?

Comment: Sorry didn't realise that. I will delete Rossi's one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no “one size fits all” presentation template...

List the headings for what you need to say and cover then go from there.

So:
1. Bio

2. Intro
3. Etc

You need to anticipate what questions may be asked and that helps focus on what you should cover. Usually the issues and solutions are interesting...

Comment: Can you explain what "Bio" is?

Comment: @user114084 your BIOgraphy - who you are...

Comment: Thank you! I waa thinking about biology:)